# Show message after contact form validated - Bootstrap Validation

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am working with this [Bootstrap Plugin](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/?underwear=on#validator-options) and I just want to make the confirmation submit message appear ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prt73nzp/)) as soon as the form is validated.

The developer of the plugin notes the following:

> When the form is invalid, .preventDefault() is called on the submit
>   event. As a result, if you want to hook into the submit event and do
>   something conditionally based on whether or not the form was valid,
>   you can check if the event .isDefaultPrevented(). Be sure your submit
>   handler is bound after the plugin has been initialized on your form.

So after few tries I just came out with this code (which does not work):

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.alert').hide()
    }) 
  } else {
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.alert').show()
    }) 
  }
})
```

What am I exactly missing?

**UPDATE**

As @Nikhil Nanjappa provided the solution I came out with another problem, since the contact form reloads the content, the message is shown one milisecond ([JSFiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/prt73nzp/1/)). Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

**UPDATE2**

For make it work, I just added handled the form submission on the "submit" event and added `return false` so the code looks like this:

```
$('#form').on('valid.bs.validator', function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.alert').show()
             return false;
    }) 
    $('.alert').delay(3000).fadeOut( "slow" );

});
```

Comment: Where is your <form> in your code and fiddle ?

Comment: I also dont see where you refere to the plugin in your fiddle .. you only use bootstrap ressources not the plugin..

Comment: Sorry, Fiddle updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same link reference you had given, I found this event [here](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/?underwear=on#validator-events).

`valid.bs.validator` - This event is fired when a form field becomes valid. Previous field errors are provided.

```
$('#someFormId').on('valid.bs.validator', function(){
    showTheMessage();
});
```

Simple and Clean. You don't have to use if else loops all over.

**Updated:**

You need to make couple of changes:

- Firstly the `validator.js` is not even working in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prt73nzp/1/) because its calling the URL via http protocol and from JSFiddle it should be https, so change the external resource URL of validator.js to `https://1000hz.gi...`.
- Secondly, the form as I see has 2 id's. Keep the one your using(`formulario-cdb`).
- This is the main culprit of reload, without having any submit handlers the form is getting submitted so it only meant the "Send button" is of type `submit`. change this to `type="button"`

Now you can see the alert display and stick there without page reloading.

Comment: Thank you, this work flawless, but right now I am facing another problem since the contact form reloads the page, so the message is not shown at all.

Comment: Ok, so now you mean, you need the message after the page reloads ? or you want to just extend the message shown time and let the page reload after ?

Comment: I just wanted to show the message when the contact form has been validated, and keep it on the screen. My solution was just handled the form submission on the "submit" event and added return false

Comment: Already solved it, check my update and thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

in submit handler you have to show or hide alert.but in your code,your are registering event listeners for button click.it just registers the event and wont fire alert.
change the code as below

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {

        $('.alert').hide()

  } else {

        $('.alert').show()

  }
})
```

Comment: When adding your code, the message does not appear.

Comment: have to show your markup and implementation to help further. can you create some fiddle and share in question